# Conditional Python argument passing

Tags: python

I writing a method in python with this prototype

```
def pick_filter(self, adult: bool = True, 
                children: bool = True, 
                rooms: bool = True, 
                count: List[int], 
                children_age: List[int] = None) -> None
```

I want that the children_age argument must be passed when the children argument is passed.
I tried to implement it in the function with conditional statement but it made the code very complicated.
Is there a more nit way to realize this use case? Maybe a decorator or something already implemented in core python 
Note: The project is about web scrapping using selenium

Comment: `if children and not children_age: raise ValueError('children_age is required')`… How complicated can it be…?

Comment: Why do you need `children: bool` at all? Why not just `children_age: Optional[List[int]]`, and if that `is not None` that implicitly means `children == True`?

Comment: This should probably be separate methods, one for adults and one for children. Does `pick_filter` make sense if neither or both of `adult` and `children` are set to `True`?

Comment: @chepner I think `adult` means "is an adult" and `children` means "has children"

Comment: @pigrammer Just a slightly different question then: does it make sense for `adult=False` and `children=True`?

Comment: Yes; It's possible for non-adults to have children. This doesn't necessarily apply to bigginer_sama's usecase, but in general I would say it makes sense.

Comment: @pigrammer sorry I didn't provide the context of the arguments. I scrapping a web site (booking.com) and creating a bot to automate reservation. If you inspect the web page you will find in the menu of reservation default values for parent children and rooms so I tried to simulate that in this method

Comment: The project is still on going so it may have a lot of flows like that the adult value must always be True so I must take it of the arguments and the room default value must be 1. So it still has a little work to do

Answer (score 0):

You should just let `children_age` being `None` represent having no children. However, you have a typing error - `children_age` should be `Optional[List[int]]`. Also, if you're using Python 3.10 or later, you can simplify your code slightly by not importing things from typing:

```py
def pick_filter(self, adult: bool = True, 
                rooms: bool = True, 
                count: list[int], 
                children_age: list[int] | None = None) -> None
```